# Android - EditText made programmatically not showing keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-appcompat

I am making an app where I am using a `ArrayAdapter<String>` and I am programmatically making an editText view inside of a Relative Layout which is all inside of a `AppCompatDialogFragment`. Each of the editTexts are showing up and I can click on them, but if it doesn't open the keyboard to type. I have tried things like:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Even if I try to manually open the keyboard, it still doesn't open.

```
        RelativeLayout listLayout = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());
        listLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                75));

        if(super.getItem(position) == ParameterTypes.String.toString()) {
            EditText editText = new EditText(this.getContext());
            editText.setWidth(500);
            editText.setHint(parameterNames[position]);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            listLayout.addView(editText);
        } else if(super.getItem(position) == ParameterTypes.Integer.toString()) {
            EditText editText = new EditText(this.getContext());
            editText.setWidth(500);
            editText.setHint(parameterNames[position]);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            listLayout.addView(editText);
        } else if(super.getItem(position) == ParameterTypes.Double.toString()) {
            EditText editText = new EditText(this.getContext());
            editText.setWidth(500);
            editText.setHint(parameterNames[position]);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
            listLayout.addView(editText);
        return listLayout;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

in xml

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, s.mhmd for your answer! I can't put it in the xml though, because I am creating this Edit Text from code only. Would it still work?

Comment: try add >>  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" -> in manifest File.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to call `imm.showSoftInput [...]` somewhat delayed with `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){...}, 100L);` since it takes time until the `requestFocus()` is effective, especially when your application is just starting up / your views. What you can also try is to call the `requestFocus()` delayed the same way.

Comment: Thanks, Lurzapps for the quick response. I didn't quite get what you meant above. Could you please explain?

Comment: I once had the problem that I called the requestFocus too early, and it took me till I finally realized I have to call it delayed

Comment: Oh, that makes a whole lot more sense! Thanks so much, Lurzapps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set focusable programmatically:

`editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`